# Selecting non-contiguous columns as graph source

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select non-contiguous columns as source of graph, I tried:

```vb
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range("B1:B2", "E1:E3"), _
  PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

The code is adding columns B to E. I want column B and column E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Worksheet.Range property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range) has two parameters:

| Name | Required/Optional | Data type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell1 | Required | Variant | A String that is a range reference when one argument is used. Either a String that is a range reference or a Range object when two arguments are used. |
| Cell2 | Optional | Variant | Either a String that is a range reference or a Range object. Cell2 defines another extremity of the range returned by the property. |

Because `Range("B1:B2", "E1:E3")` is `Range(a, b)` that means range from `a` to `b`.

You probably meant `Range("B1:B2,E1:E3")` which means a non-continous range of `B1:B2` and `E1:E3`.